# Setting php.ini variables inside web.config on IIS 7.5

Tags: php, iis, webserver

Is there any way to set the usual php.ini variables on an IIS 7.5 server, using web.config files? I'd like to set short_open_tag and environment variables.

Comment: that's completely false. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754617(WS.10).aspx Web.config files in your sites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<fastCgi>
  <application fullPath="C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe">
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="PHPRC" value="C:\WebSites\website1" />
    </environmentVariables>
  </application>
  <application fullPath="C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe">
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="PHPRC" value="C:\WebSites\website2" />
    </environmentVariables>
  </application>
</fastCgi>
```

Or as http://ruslany.net/2009/07/per-site-php-configuration-with-php-5-3-and-iis/ says, add `user_ini.filename = .user.ini` to php.ini and drop `.user.ini` files in the root of the sites.